# Control not returning to the waiting thread after notify

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I created a new thread called `ThreadA` and started that in the main thread.

I waited for some operations to be completed in `ThreadA`.

After some operations I sent notification using `notify`.

But the code below the `wait` in the main thread is not called, it waits for the entire code of the `ThreadA` to complete.

Is it the nature of threading or simply thread getting access to run problem?

```
Job job = new MyJob(); 
job.schedule(); 
synchronized(job) {
    job.wait(); 
    sysout("After notify");
}
```

Here `job` is org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs

Inside Job run method:

```
run {
    synchronized(this) {
        step 1(); 
        notify(); 
        step 2();
    }
}
```

Here step 2 is big code.

Comment: Please show your code (how exactly you're calling `wait` and `notify`).

Comment: Job job =new MyJob(); job.schedule(); synchronized(job){job.wait(); sysout("After notify")} Here job is org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.

Comment: Inside Job run method :   run {synchronized(this){step 1(); notify(); step 2();}} Here step 2 is big code.

Comment: My code first goes to step 2 and only after completing step 2 calls sysout in main thread

Comment: May I suggest to replace `wait()` and `notify()` with something more modern like the utility classes offered by [java concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The notifying thread doesn't actually send the notification until it releases the lock. You need to release the lock before the notification can happen, and your code isn't doing that.

Then the thread receiving the notification doesn't have the lock, of course. It has to acquire the lock before it can act, if the thread is waiting it needs to acquire the lock before it can exit the wait method. There's no preference for the notified thread and no reason to think it has to be first to act next.

This is part of why it's advised to always call wait in a loop, which you're not doing. The waking thread should check whether the condition it was woken up for is still true once it has obtained the lock.

Your Job run method holds onto the lock all the way from calling step1 through calling step2. For the notified thread to do anything about the notification it has to stop waiting, which entails re-acquiring the lock before it can exit the wait method (because it has to enter its own synchronized block). That means there's no point sending the notification before the notifying thread releases the lock, becuase there's nothing the waiting thread can do about it anyway.

Comment: Does  Synchronized(job) acquire the lock on that object?

Comment: @user3302323 the `synchronize` keyword marks a block that can only be entered by a single thread at the same time. If an other thread is currently in a synchronized block on the same object, the execution is paused until the other thread has left its synchronized block

Comment: Can you please explain in detail how to release and acquire locks on object?

Comment: @user3302323 Please read through [the documentation on instrinsic locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html). Hopefully you will learn that the lock is released once the synchronization block is left (think of it as when the execution pointer passed the `}` symbol) or an exception occurred within the synchronized block which was not handled by a try-catch block inside the synchronized block

Comment: public class ThreadMain {
 
 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println("In main");
 ThreadMain main=new ThreadMain();
 ThreadA runnable =new ThreadA(main);
 Thread thread=new Thread(runnable);
 
 thread.start();
 synchronized (runnable) {
  
  try {
   runnable.wait();
   System.out.println("Thread notified");  
  } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
   exp.printStackTrace();
  }
  
 }
 
 }

}

Comment: public class ThreadA implements Runnable {

 private ThreadMain main;

 public ThreadA(ThreadMain main) {
this.main=main;
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
  
  synchronized (this) {
   System.out.println("Thread Start");
   
   for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
    System.out.println(i);
   }
   
   notify();

   for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
    System.out.println(i);
   }
   System.out.println("Threasd end");
  }

 
 }

}

Comment: Above two are the code for main class and thread. The code below notify() always executes and after thread completion code comes to main.Why?

Comment: @user3302323 simply as the `notify()` is fired once the synchronization block is left and not at the position it is within the code actually! But this was already mentioned by @NathanHughes in his answer. Try to reduce the scope of the synchronized block to only the notify method invocation but not the loops and re-run your tests again